# Default Value when Deserialize in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, serialization, dictionary, deserialization, vb.net-2010

I have a (Serializable) class (Accounts), and inside this class some properties, including a Dictionary of another Serializable class (Symbols).

I Serialize the class (Accounts) and save them into a file to be used for next run.

Now, I have a new version of the application, which contain a new properties inside (Symbols) class. When I Deserialize the (Accounts), it loads the Dictionary correctly, but with un-desired values (the strings are nothing and the booleans are false).

Can I set a default values for those new properties inside the Symbols class when I deserialize? Note that I want this without a For loop, since the Dictionary of Accounts and the Symbols are large, which means I will need a huge double for loop to solve this using for loop.

Thanks.
Ahmad

Comment: I managed to work-around this case by making all my variables as Strings (to be handled as objects), and within my code, I check if the value is Nothing, then I will assign the default value when needed...
I know this is not the best solution, but at least it worked out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work-around this case by making all my variables as Strings (to be handled as objects), and within my code, I check if the value is Nothing, then I will assign the default value when needed... I know this is not the best solution, but at least it worked out!

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify a default value for each property:

For backing fields:

```
Private _someProperty as Boolean = True
```

For auto-Implemented Properties:

```
Public Property SomeProperty As Boolean = True
```

Comment: Adding a default value to the private variable will not work. 
It seems that after reading the dictionary from the serialization, it will override this by (Nothing) in case of strings and objects, and with (0's and False's) in case of numeric and boolean variables...

Comment: I managed to work-around this case by making all my variables as Strings (to be handled as objects), and within my code, I check if the value is Nothing, then I will assign the default value when needed... I know this is not the best solution, but at least it worked out!